# How to configure a github repository as a config repo for spring cloud server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have created a github repository `https://github.com/Nisarg04/microservices-config-repo.git`, which I want to be treated as a config repo. Also, I have a spring cloud server, which picks properties from local repo (as per current configuration). I want that to be picked from github repo.
`application.properties` looks something like this :

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/Users/admin/git/git-localconfig-repo
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/Nisarg04/microservices-config-repo.git
management.security.enabled=false
```

When I point to `git-localconfig-repo`, it works perfect. But, when I make it to point my repo, it gives be error as `Cannot clone or checkout repository: https://github.com/Nisarg04/microservices-config-repo.git`

How do I resolve this?

**EDIT :** Also tried 
`spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=nisarg04`
`spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=mypassword`
but even this dint help

As requested I have added server class below:

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableConfigServer
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information to help. Is the repo private? Does the machine config server is have access to GitHub?

Comment: Repo is public. I didn't understand your second question, but I do have this repo cloned on my local machine.

Comment: Can you share your config server class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue and find the solution.

**FIX:**
Skip SSL validation by adding **`skip-ssl-validation=true`** in `application.properties` when accessing the Git repo:

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/Users/admin/git/git-localconfig-repo
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/Nisarg04/microservices-config-repo.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip-ssl-validation=true
management.security.enabled=false
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Accepted the answer. Cheers!

Comment: But I'm able to access your config repository without setting this flag to false.

Comment: `skip-ssl-validation=true` this is the flag that resolved the issue

Comment: `management.security.enabled=false` seems to be deprecated, should be replaced by `WebSecurityConfigurer`, can anyone please help me understand how do I use `WebSecurityConfigurer`? I searched for some content to start with, but unfortunately did not help.

Comment: @NisargPatil when you implement WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter try adding this: http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .and()
    .httpBasic().disable();