# External URL configuration in microservice

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, microservices

I have multiple microservices which communicates with each other through REST calls.
I have used spring boot and spring rest and have configured the URLS of the rest end points in application.properties file.
Now the problems is if the URL for one end point changes then I to have to manually modify all the property files of the services which are calling that particular end point which has got changed.

Is there a  workaround for this so that the URLS can be somehow placed in a centralized location so that any modification does not impacts the other services which are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spring-cloud to achieve this. Usual way used in spring-cloud is by configuring the required properties in a git repo. And then those properties can be accessed by any micro-service you want with minimal configurations. You can refer [projects in this repo](https://github.com/Nisarg04/Spring-microservices)
`limits-services` acts as a client that needs certain properties those are configured in `spring-cloud-config-server`. Hope this helps.

Comment: In case you face any authentication issue [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52646183/7088682)

Answer (score 1):

In case with microservices you can use **Spring Cloud Config** ([Spring Cloud Config](http://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config), [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html)). It's very usefull and you can update your configuration at runtime.

> Spring Cloud Config provides server and client-side support for externalized configuration in a distributed system. With the Config Server you have a central place to manage external properties for applications across all environments. The concepts on both client and server map identically to the Spring Environment and PropertySource abstractions, so they fit very well with Spring applications, but can be used with any application running in any language. As an application moves through the deployment pipeline from dev to test and into production you can manage the configuration between those environments and be certain that applications have everything they need to run when they migrate.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you can use `Spring Cloud Config Server` to remotly load your application configuration. All you need is `git` repository containing your configuration.

Spring cloud configuration supporst Git, database as your store for configuration.

Idea is to create an spring-boot app that can provide configuration to other applications.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConfigServer.class, args);
  }
}
```

You can configurae port and provide your git repository using key `spring.cloud.config.server`

```
server.port: 8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri: file://${user.home}/config-repo
```

At client side, if you have spring-config in your classpath, application will try to connect to an application runnign at port 8888 to retrieve configuration.

More information can be found [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html).

Answer (score 0):

may put configuration inside a database.
 
after that need have one centralize cache service that used by other services, can be .jar service,
then the values can be load inside a cache class in this service, 
then in the front end side need have update button for updating the cache after modify the URL value in the database, so then all impacted services can use new value. 
and also to be easier may have stand alone UI for update those configuration rather than updating database directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microconfig.IO](https://microconfig.io) to manage your service configuration and it's placeholders functionality to reference configuration values of certain services from others. So in your case you configure your deploy url in your server and put placeholders on it in your clients. This allows you to edit value only in one place and then everyone who depend on it will get it automatically.